# Python Tkinter Treeview - Iterating 'get_children' output

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, children

I am trying to later iterate through the data inside of the Treeview. I will then hope to be able to sort through it.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import pickle

root = Tk()

def treeData(event):
    children = tree.get_children()
    print(children)

entry = StringVar()
a = Entry(root, textvariable=entry)
a.grid(column=0,row=0)
a.bind("<Key>", function)

file_data = []
file = open('data.dat', 'rb')
while True:
    try:
        file_data.append(pickle.load(file))
    except EOFError:
        break
file.close()

column_names = ("Column 1", "Column 2")
tree = Treeview(root, columns=column_names)
tree['show'] = 'headings'
for x in file_data:
    a = tree.insert('', 'end', values=x)
for col in column_names: 
    tree.heading(col, text=col)

tree.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

In the function, called 'treeData' when I print(children) it outputs a list that looks similar to this - ('I001', 'I002', 'I003', 'I004')

I am hoping someone will know how to convert these pieces of data into what is actually shown in the row of the Treeview?

Thanks,

Comment: Without example or dummy version of `loans.dat` cant help much.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you are asking is documented in the official tkinter [documentation for the Treeview widget](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#ttk-treeview).

The [get_children](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.get_children) method returns a list of item IDs, one for each child. The [item](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Treeview.item) method of the treeview will return a dictionary of data for a given item. Thus, you can iterate over the values with something like this:

```
for child in tree.get_children():
    print(tree.item(child)["values"])
```

Comment: What's interesting here is as far as I understand those `I001`, `I002` etc. are default `iid` values Tkinter provides if not supplied with anything. Now, the interesting part begins when someone (that would be me) gets a brilliant idea to use list indexes when populating a tree (seems like a nice way of circumventing hassle of translating selected items back into objects they originated from) and then learns that item `0` produces back `I001` instead. Probably Tkinter treats supplying `0` for `iid` as not supplying anything. That's my guess at least.

Comment: Also, I think if you used index values (a fine idea... at first!) will result in obscene complications later. If items are added or removed, or the list is sorted, the Iid=index values will all be wrong.