# How to sum a Treeview's values in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sum, treeview

I'm developing a GUI where the idea is to add some values to a treeview (as a billing system) and then get the result or sum of all items' prices.

[image: A shot of the GUI, and "Generar" button result in the terminal]
The button "Agregar" (Add in English) get the Entries' data and add them to the treevew; one of them if the amount of money to pay.
Now what I want, and haven't been able to get, is the sum of the values given in the treeview to be shown in the field or entry which is below the treeview when "Generar" (Generate in English) button is pressed.

Next, the code I got:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from Tkinter import*
from ttk import Combobox, Treeview
from tkMessageBox import*
import MySQLdb
from controller import *
import math

class Gastos(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        #INSTANCIAS
        global cc, nombre, pago, ref, cod, desc, valor
        #INSTANCIAS DE LOS WIDGETS
        global e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, tree, l8

        cc = IntVar()
        nombre = StringVar()
        pago = StringVar()
        ref = StringVar()
        cod = StringVar()
        desc = StringVar()
        valor = DoubleVar()

        tbancos = ['Bancolombia', "Banco Bogotá", "Banco Agrario", "Banco Occidente"]

        lupa = PhotoImage(file='img/lupa.png')

        tbanktype = ['Corriente','Ahorro']
        fpago = ['Efectivo','Transferencia']

        resultado = DoubleVar()

        #BUSQUEDA = ["Nombre","CC/Nit"]
        busqueda = StringVar()
        busqueda.trace("w", lambda name, index, mode: buscar())
        dato = StringVar()

        #WIDGETS

        #========================= HEADER ==============================

        self.titleL = Label(self, text="GASTOS", font="bold")
        self.titleL.pack(pady=20, side=TOP)

        #========================== WRAPPER ============================

        self.wrapper = Frame (self)
        self.wrapper.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)
        #Esto centro el wrapper
        #self.wrapper.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        #======================== BENEFICIARIO =======================

        self.lf1 = LabelFrame(self.wrapper, text="Beneficiario")
        self.lf1.pack(fill=X, ipady=5)

        self.f0 = Frame(self.lf1)
        self.f0.pack(pady=5, fill=X)#-----------------------------------

        l1 = Label(self.f0, text='CC/Nit:')
        l1.pack(side=LEFT)

        e1 = Entry(self.f0, textvariable=cc)
        e1.pack(side=LEFT)

        b0 = Button(self.f0, text='Buscar:', image=lupa, command=buscarB)
        b0.pack(side=LEFT)

        l2 = Label(self.f0, text='Nombre:')
        l2.pack(side=LEFT)
        e2 = Entry(self.f0, textvariable=nombre)
        e2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)

        self.f1 = Frame(self.lf1)
        self.f1.pack(pady=5, fill=X)#-----------------------------------

        l3 = Label(self.f1, text='Forma de Pago:')
        l3.pack(side=LEFT)
        Cbx = Combobox(self.f1, textvariable=pago, values=fpago, width=15)
        Cbx.set('Efectivo')
        Cbx.pack(side=LEFT)

        l4 = Label(self.f1, text='Ref. Bancaria:')
        l4.pack(side=LEFT)
        e3 = Entry(self.f1, textvariable=ref)
        e3.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)

        b1 = Button(self.f1, text='Buscar:', image=lupa)
        b1.image=lupa
        b1.pack(side=LEFT)

        #======================== CONCEPTO ========================

        self.lf2 = LabelFrame(self.wrapper, text="Concepto")
        self.lf2.pack(fill=X, ipady=5)

        self.f2 = Frame(self.lf2)
        self.f2.pack(pady=5, fill=X)#-------------------------------

        l5 = Label(self.f2, text='Código:')
        l5.pack(side=LEFT)
        e4 = Entry(self.f2, textvariable=cod)
        e4.pack(side=LEFT)

        b2 = Button(self.f2, text='Buscar:', image=lupa, command=buscarC)
        b2.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.f3 = Frame(self.lf2)
        self.f3.pack(pady=5, fill=X)#-------------------------------

        l6 = Label(self.f3, text='Descripción:')
        l6.pack(side=LEFT)
        e5 = Entry(self.f3, textvariable=desc, state=DISABLED)
        e5.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)

        l7 = Label(self.f3, text='Valor:')
        l7.pack(side=LEFT)
        e6 = Entry(self.f3, width=15, textvariable=valor)
        e6.pack(side=LEFT)

        b3 = Button(self.f3, text='Agregar:', command=agregar)
        b3.pack(side=LEFT)

        #-------------------------- TREEVIEW ---------------------------

        self.f4 = Frame(self.wrapper)
        self.f4.pack(pady=5,fill=X)

        tree = Treeview(self.f4, height=4, show="headings", columns=('col1','col2','col3'))
        tree.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
        tree.column('col1', width=20, anchor='center')
        tree.column('col2', width=200, anchor='center')
        tree.column('col3', width=10, anchor='center')

        tree.heading('col1', text='Código')
        tree.heading('col2', text='Concepto')
        tree.heading('col3', text='Valor')

        scroll = Scrollbar(self.f4,orient=VERTICAL,command=tree.yview)
        tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)

        #--------------------------------------------------------------

        self.f5 = Frame(self.wrapper)
        self.f5.pack(pady=5,fill=X)#-------------------

        #RESULT MUST BE SHOWN HERE
        l8 = Label(self.f5, text=resultado, fg="red", bg="white", anchor='e', font="bold, 22", relief= SUNKEN)
        l8.pack(fill=X, side=RIGHT, expand=1)
        #l8.set("link")

        self.fBtn = Frame(self.wrapper)
        self.fBtn.pack()#-------------------------------

        clean = Button(self.fBtn, text='Cancelar', bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', command=limpiar)
        clean.pack(side=RIGHT)

        update = Button(self.fBtn, text='Actualizar', bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', state=DISABLED)
        update.pack(side=RIGHT)

        add = Button(self.fBtn, text='Generar', bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', command=generar)
        add.pack(side=RIGHT)

        #========================= ASIDE ===========================

        self.aside = Frame(self)
        self.aside.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)

        self.wrap1 = Frame(self.aside)
        self.wrap1.pack()

        self.viewer = Label(self.wrap1, text="LISTA DE GASTOS")
        self.viewer.pack()

        scroll = Scrollbar(self.wrap1, orient=VERTICAL)
        scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        lb = Listbox(self.wrap1, yscrollcommand=scroll.set, height=20, width=30)
        scroll.config (command=lb.yview)
        lb.pack(fill=BOTH)
        lb.bind("<Double-Button-1>", callback)

        self.wrap2 = Frame(self.aside)
        self.wrap2.pack()

        load = Button(self.wrap2, text='Cargar lista', bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', command=cargar_lista)
        load.pack(fill=X)

        delete = Button(self.wrap2, text='Borrar', bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', command=borrar)
        delete.pack(fill=X)

        edit = Button(self.wrap2, text='Modificar', bg='navy', foreground='white', activebackground='red3', activeforeground='white', command=modificar)
        edit.pack(fill=X)

        buscador = Label(self.wrap2, text="Buscar por Número:")
        buscador.pack()
        E = Entry(self.wrap2, textvariable=busqueda, width=24)
        E.pack()
        E.bind("<KeyRelease>", caps)

def cargar_lista():
    try:
        connect.commit()
        display = "SELECT g_num FROM detalles order by g_num;"
        cursor.execute(display)
        registros = cursor.fetchall()
        lb.delete(0, END)
        for item in registros:
            #print item
            num = item[0]
            lb.insert(END, num)
    except:
        showerror("Mensaje", "Ha ocurrido un error")

# NUEVO / CANCELAR
def limpiar():
    tree.delete(*tree.get_children())
    pass

def agregar():
    v1 = cc.get()
    v2 = None
    v3 = cod.get()
    v4 = desc.get()
    v5 = valor.get()
    tree.insert('', 0, values=(v3,v4,v5))

#FUNCTION THAT GIVE THE VALUES
def generar():
    children = tree.get_children()#OBTIENE LOS iid DE LOS ITEMS
    for child in children:
        i = tree.item(child, 'values')[2]#OBTIENE LOS VALORES DE LOS ITEMS
        print i

def borrar():
    pass

def bloquear():
    pass

def callback(event):
    llenar_campos()

def llenar_campos():
    pass

def habilitar():
    pass

def modificar():
    pass

def actualizar():
    pass

def buscar():
    pass

def buscarB():
    connect.commit()
    try:
        v = cc.get()
        sql = "SELECT b_nombre from beneficiarios WHERE b_cc='%d';" % (v)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        query = cursor.fetchone()
        for n in query:
            nombre.set(n)
    except TypeError, e:
        showerror("Error", e)

    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError, e:
        showerror("Error", e)

def buscarC():
    connect.commit()
    try:
        v = cod.get()
        sql = "SELECT cg_nombre from concepto_gastos WHERE cg_cod='%s';" % (v)
        cursor.execute(sql)
        query = cursor.fetchone()
        for n in query:
            desc.set(n)
    except TypeError, e:
        showerror("Error", e)

    except MySQLdb.IntegrityError, e:
        showerror("Error", e)
    except:
         showerror ("Mensaje", "No se encuentra!")

# CONVIERTE LA ENTRADA DE LOS ENTRIES EN MAYÚSCULA
def caps(event):
    pass
```

The code is not finished, that's why it has so much info. But next function is what give me the values I need to be sum:

```
def generar():
    children = tree.get_children()#OBTIENE LOS iid DE LOS ITEMS
    for child in children:
        i = tree.item(child, 'values')[2]#OBTIENE LOS VALORES DE LOS ITEMS
        print i
```

By the way, this file is called by another (home.py) to interact with it.

If anyone could give me a hand this problem, you'll save a life. Thanks for your time, look on this, and anything you could answer. Sorry for my English if it is not good.

Comment: I think everything you have so far is correct. You just need to make an integer variable and sum it up. Alternately you can make this much more compact using a generator(I think, I'm not familiar with generators). Good luck.

Comment: keep all information in some list (not only in TreeView) to have easy access to this information.

Comment: or create variable for total_sum and add value inside `agregar()`

Comment: I'd like to know how to keep the info in some list for what u said, to have easy access. But that's a topic hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert string to float and then you can add to variable ie. `total`

```
def generar():

    total = 0.0

    for child in tree.get_children():
        total += float(tree.item(child, 'values')[2])

    print total
```

But you could add value even in `agregar` to get `total` with using button

```
# create global variables
total = 0.0
# or 
total_var = DoubleVar()

def agregar():
    # inform function to use external/global variable when you use `+=`
    global total

    v1 = cc.get()
    v2 = None
    v3 = cod.get()
    v4 = desc.get()
    v5 = valor.get()

    total += v5
    # or
    total_var.set(total_var.get() + v5)

    tree.insert('', 0, values=(v3,v4,v5))
```

Full working example

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

# --- functions ---

def agregar(v3, v4, v5):
    tree.insert('', 0, values=(v3,v4,v5))

def generar():

    total = 0.0

    for child in tree.get_children():
        total += float(tree.item(child, 'values')[2])

    print total

    result['text'] = 'Total: {}'.format(total)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height=4, show="headings", columns=('col1','col2','col3'))
tree.pack()

tree.heading('col1', text='Código')
tree.heading('col2', text='Concepto')
tree.heading('col3', text='Valor')

add = tk.Button(root, text='Generar', command=generar)
add.pack()

result = tk.Label(root, text='Total: 0')
result.pack()

agregar("1", "AAA", 1.11)
agregar("2", "BBB", 2.22)
agregar("3", "CCC", 3.33)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah, this info made it! But now I realized that "Generar" button could be usefull to generate the PDF bill with Reportlab library, and "Agregar" button to go summing the values in the field meant for it, and inserting the data into the Treeview. But what about if I want to delete a row from the treeview by pressing Supr or Delete key, and get the subtraction result. How would it be?

Comment: I created the following function to delete a selected row:

def borrar(event):
                i = tree.selection()[0]
                tree.delete(i)

Also, I added tree.bind("<Delete>", borrar) where the treeview is, and it does its job, but how to subtract the deleted value to the result?

Comment: simply create function which sum elements in table and execute it when you add new element or remove old one.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting PY_VAR240 is because your code is trying to display an object instead of a value.

There is already an answer here that hints at the issue as well: [Python Tkinter Treeview - Iterating 'get_children' output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685048/python-tkinter-treeview-iterating-get-children-output)

Also here is how I get the values from a row:

```
rowItem = treeSomeTree.item(itemID)
itemDictionary = rowItem['values']
someVariable = itemDictionary[0]
```

Note the item id variable represents row item identifier which may or may not be a number and must be unique.  The treeview .insert defaults to None (iid=None) if not specified.

By specifying the iid as an integer value as you inert rows you will always know which row you have (or need to get) to summarize.

Comment: Oh yeah, u're right! Now, I noticed the "l8" Label has 'text' rather than textvariable, and variable 'resultado' isn't  global.